# Loop through a large range/array to manipulate data

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, large-data

I have a data range in Excel sheet_1 A10:H50000.

I need to find in column C a match of the text "40GP", if a match is found, the current row needs to be duplicated with an updated text value "40HC" in column C for the new row.
Eventually I need the updated array, including the new rows of "40HC", be written back to the sheet and overwrite the data range (A10:H50000).

Using the for loop method, code execution takes so long to complete. I attempted to use an array.

My VBA code using array after consulting ChatGPT 3.5. With this, there are many blank rows in the updated array.

My goal is to create a duplicate line for the current row that has "40GP" in column C and change the "40GP" with "40HC" for the new row and write the updated array back to the sheet in the same location, in a faster way than looping through the range.

```vb
Sub UpdateDataQuick()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim newData As Variant
    Dim newRowCount As Long

    ' Assuming your data is in the active sheet. You can modify this accordingly.
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Read data into an array for faster processing
    data = ws.Range("A10:H" & lastRow).Value

    ' Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(i, 3) = "40GP" Then
            ' Duplicate the current row
            newRowCount = newRowCount + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Resize the new data array
    ReDim newData(1 To UBound(data, 1) + newRowCount, 1 To UBound(data, 2))

    ' Populate the new data array
    newRowCount = 0
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(i, 3) = "40GP" Then
            newRowCount = newRowCount + 1
            ' Duplicate the current row
            For j = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
                newData(i + newRowCount, j) = data(i, j)
            Next j
            ' Update the value in column C to "40HC"
            newData(i + newRowCount, 3) = "40HC"
        Else
            ' Copy the current row to the new array
            For j = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            newData(i + newRowCount, j) = data(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    ' Write the updated data back to the worksheet
    ws.Range("A10").Resize(UBound(newData, 1), UBound(newData, 2)).Value = newData

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: 50000 records is not that big... Does it have to be in VBA?

Comment: Hi algiogia unfortunately yes it has to be vba script.

Comment: When col C is "40GP" you only write the "extra" row - you also need to write the original row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: updated to show full code, pushed array row copy into separate sub.

Like this maybe:

```
Sub UpdateDataQuick()
    
    Const FLAG_COL As Long = 3
    Const FLAG As String = "40GP"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, data As Variant, newData As Variant, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, rwOut As Long, addRows As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A10:H" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    data = rngData.Value
    addRows = Application.CountIf(rngData.Columns(FLAG_COL), FLAG)
    
    ReDim newData(1 To UBound(data, 1) + addRows, 1 To UBound(data, 2))
    
    rwOut = 0 'row index for output array
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        CopyRow data, i, newData, rwOut
        If data(i, 3) = "40GP" Then
            CopyRow data, i, newData, rwOut
            newData(rwOut, FLAG_COL) = "40HC"
        End If
    Next i
    'put output array on sheet (non-overlapping for testing)
    ws.Range("J10").Resize(UBound(newData, 1), UBound(newData, 2)).Value = newData

End Sub

'Copy data from 2-D array `arrSrc` at row index `rwSrc` to array `arrDest`
'  Increment destination array row index `rwOut` by 1 before the copy
'Assumed both arrays have the same # of columns
Sub CopyRow(arrSrc, rwSrc As Long, arrDest, ByRef rwOut As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    rwOut = rwOut + 1 ' increment output row index
    For i = LBound(arrSrc, 2) To UBound(arrSrc, 2)
        arrDest(rwOut, i) = arrSrc(rwSrc, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: exactly what i needed - the reordered statement of the rwout = rwout + 1, has really changed the game - plus i learned the use of IIF - that's bonus. Thank you Tim!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need VBA, however, I would guess this is faster than using the vba loop.

```
Sub FixSomeData()
    Dim myVals()

    myVals = Evaluate("=LET(zStart,FILTER(A10:H999999,A10:A999999<>""""),changeData,FILTER(IF(zStart=""40GP"",""40HC"",zStart),CHOOSECOLS(zStart,2)=""40GP""),VSTACK(zStart,changeData))")
    Range("A10").Resize(UBound(myVals), 8) = myVals

End Sub
```

Comment: That's one brilliant workaround solution - never thought of the IF function can be used as search+substitute in this way - amzaing ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a combination of sorting an filtering cells could be an effective no-array solution even with large data

I'm assuming:

- row 9 has headers
- column "I" is free for use a "helper" one (otherwise the code can be tweaked to use the first free column)

here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDataQuickWithoutArray()

    'reference range with headers and data
    With Range("H9", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        
        'write an "ordering" number in a helper column next to data
        With .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=Row()"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        
        'extend referenced range to the helper column
        With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
        
            ' sort referenced range by its 3rd column
            .Sort key1:=.Columns(3), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   
            'filter referenced range on its 3rd column so as to have rows with "40GP" visible only
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="40GP"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1))) Then
                        Dim rng As Range
                        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' store filtered range
                    End If
                End With
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            
                ' if any "40GP" rows have been detected
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                
                    rng.Insert shift:=xlDown ' insert as many new rows as "40GP" ones right before them
                    
                    With rng ' reference the "40GP" range
                        .Copy .Offset(-.Rows.Count) ' copy the content of filtered rows into the new ones
                        With .Offset(-.Rows.Count) ' reference the new ones
                            .Columns(3).Value = "40HC" ' change "40GP" tp "40HC"
                            With .Columns(.Columns.Count) 'reference the new rows "helper" column
                                .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[" & rng.Rows.Count & "]C +0.1" ' assign an "ordering" number close to the "40GP" ones
                                .Value = .Value
                            End With
                        End With
                    End With
                
                End If
                
                'sort back
                .Sort key1:=.Columns(.Columns.Count), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                
                'clear the "helper" column
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).ClearContents
            
        End With
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you are correct on using a combo of sorting and filtering as the other user suggested here. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You are welcome. And it'd be fine to know what's the fastest method

Comment: @user3598756 I am curious myself, I may setup a test later right after I knockout my important task of trying out new season of Fortnite...